# Generate a list of all combinations by replacing a character with many possibilities

Tags: r, combinations

I would like to generate a new column of a data frame containing a list of all combinations by replacing a character with many possibilities for example:

I have a table generated using this code:

```
x <- expand.grid(rep(list(c('a', 'g', 't', 'c', 'n')), 3))
xx <- data.frame(do.call(paste0, x))
tabcomb <-  droplevels(xx[grep('n',xx[,1]),,drop=TRUE])
data.frame(tabcomb)
```

It gives me a table of 61 rows, here are the 10 first rows:

```
> head(tabcomb,10)
 tabcomb
 1  naa
 2  nga
 3  nta
 4  nca
 5  ana
 6  gna
 7  tna
 8  cna
 9  nna
 10 nag
```

The letter `n` can be any of `('a', 'c', 't' or 'g')`. I would like to generate a second column containing a list of all combinations resulted by replacing the `n` letter to obtain a table having this format:

```
 tabcomb  all

 1  naa   aaa caa taa gaa
 2  nga   aga cga tga gga
 3  nta   ata cta tta gta
 4  nca   aca cca tca gca
 5  ana   aaa aca ata aga
 6  gna   gaa ...
 7  tna   taa ....
 8  cna   ........
 9  nna   aaa taa gaa caa aaa aca aga ata .....
 10 nag   .......
 11 nnn   ...............................
```

P.S. the space between combinations in the second column is not necessary (I put it in the example for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this works in the form you wanted (and gives long answers where there are 2 or 3 ns in a sequence)...

```
df<-data.frame(tabcomb)
df$A <- sapply(as.character(df$tabcomb),function(S) {
  v <- lapply(1:3,function(i) ifelse(substr(S,i,i)=="n",list(c('a', 'g', 't', 'c')),list(substr(S,i,i))))
  z <- expand.grid(v[[1]][[1]],v[[2]][[1]],v[[3]][[1]])
  zz <- paste(do.call(paste0,z),collapse=" ")
  return(zz)
})
```

Comment: Yes! this is what I need. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(tabcomb)
df$tabcomb <- as.character(df$tabcomb)

myfun <- function( x ) 
{
  a1 <- lapply( as.list( strsplit( x, '')[[1]] ), function( y ) {
    if( y == 'n') { y <- c('a', 'c', 't', 'g') }
    y
  } )
  apply( expand.grid(a1), 1, paste, collapse = '' )
}

sapply( df$tabcomb, myfun )
```